# Google Drive HTML Collaboration

Tags: google-drive

How can I allow for multiple Google Drive users to edit the same HTML document at a time?  Whenever I use an HTML file it doesn't allow it to be edited in Drive (by me or the other user).

Answer (score 1):

Only Google Drive "native" documents can be edited collaboratively. If you want to edit an HTML file that way in Google Drive you'll need to make it a Google Doc and then convert it later.

Answer (score 1):

To edit HTML files  by several users at the same time in Google Drive you need to connect an non-Google app that has that feature.

To add non-Google app,

1. Go to http://drive.google.com
2. Click on Settings (button with a gear icon) > Manage Apps

   [image: Settings - Manage Apps]
3. Click on `Connect more apps`.
4. Search and choose for an app
5. Click on `Connect`.

Note: The `Learn more` link shown in the snapshot points to [Non-Google apps in Drive - Google Drive Help](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/2500820?hl=en).